# Data from model to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this working in my controller, but I want to follow best practices and put my database logic in Model.

I want to put all database logic (select, update, delete, insert) to MODEL, therefore I create methods in my model.

My method for retrieving the data:

```
public IQueryable<ChatLogsNameViewModel> getChatLogWithName()
{
    using (var db = new ChatLogContext())
    {
        var list = (from b in db.ChatLogs
                    select new ChatLogsNameViewModel()
                    {
                        UserProfile = b.UserProfile,
                        Message = b.Message,
                        Time = b.Time
                    });

        return list;
    }
}
```

This is my modelView:

```
public class ChatLogsNameViewModel
{
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

}
```

I call my getChatLogWithName() method in my controller like this:

```
List<ChatLogsNameViewModel> items = null;
using (var dba = new ChatLogContext())
{
    items = dba.getChatLogWithName().ToList();
    return View(items);
}
```

Error I get is:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

What is the proper way to do this? I just want to pass collection (all records from 2 tables via join) to controller.

Comment: Controller is disposable. Make context a field and dispose it when controller is disposed.

Comment: I am beginner can you elaborate more please? Thank you.

Comment: @abatishchev `3ass` in title...

Comment: @sza: Sorry, a typo. Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that the DBContext is not getting referenced after disposal.  How about returning a list so you dont have to call `.ToList()`:

```
public List<ChatLogsNameViewModel> getChatLogWithName()
    {
        using (var db = new ChatLogContext())
        {
            var list = (from b in db.ChatLogs
                        select new ChatLogsNameViewModel()
                        {
                            UserProfile = b.UserProfile,
                            Message = b.Message,
                            Time = b.Time
                        });

            return list.ToList();
        }
    }
```

and

```
items = dba.getChatLogWithName();
```

Or

Since it appears that `dba` is the same as `db`, couldn't you change your code to use the `dba` instance which won't get disposed until the end of your `using` statement within your controller.

```
public IQueryable<ChatLogsNameViewModel> getChatLogWithName()
    {

            var list = (from b in this.ChatLogs
                        select new ChatLogsNameViewModel()
                        {
                            UserProfile = b.UserProfile,
                            Message = b.Message,
                            Time = b.Time
                        });

            return list;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I made a mistakes with not knowing when does dispose fires in this case. I understand what do you mean. I could use "global" context but I thought you have to use "using" in controller for more safety.

Answer (score 2):

> [Lifetime - DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx)
>
> The lifetime of the context begins when the instance is created and
>   ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use
>   using if you want all the resources that the context controls to be
>   disposed at the end of the block. When you use using, the compiler
>   automatically creates a try/finally block and calls dispose in the
>   finally block.

The problem was when the inner using got disposed, it invalidated the DbContext. So you need to use `.ToList()` to save the query result in memory.

Suppose `getChatLogWithName` is defined in the class called `Repo`, you can change the controller logic to something like this:

```
var repo = new Repo();
var items = repo.getChatLogWithName().ToList();
```

Or move `.ToList()` to `getChatLogWithName`.

Btw, you should not use the nested DbContexts cope, in your controller, you don't have to wrap it using another DbContextscope.

Comment: yes i agree, i thought that using "using" is more safe way always, so you don't need to use "using" in controllers? making private instance at top is just enough?

Comment: using is more safe. However it does not allow access to the IQueryable that is needed for WebAPI OData to work.